# Grepl() to sort through unique values?

Tags: r, function, grepl

I'm trying to find a way of using pipes to group data by part of a character vector using a function. The data is in this format:`ampXXi` or `ampXXXi` , where `XX` or `XXX`. Are the unique site codes and the `i` denotes sub-sites within each site. Is there a way of grouping the data by each `ampXXi` or `ampXXXi`? I tried to sort this with function using `grepl()`, but that didn't work. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: you need to provide a [small reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### substr() to get part of string variable for grouping

You could use `substr()` to extract the unique site ids, and use the variable to group your data.

Example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
          x = c("amp22i", "amp333i", "amp11i", "amp22i", "amp11i", "amp333i"),
          y = c(1:6), 
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df

#         x y
# 1  amp22i 1
# 2 amp333i 2
# 3  amp11i 3
# 4  amp22i 4
# 5  amp11i 5
# 6 amp333i 6
```

`substr()` to make group id variable from portion of string

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df %<>% 
  mutate(id = substr(x,4, nchar(x)))

df

#          x y   id
#  1  amp22i 1  22i
#  2 amp333i 2 333i
#  3  amp11i 3  11i
#  4  amp22i 4  22i
#  5  amp11i 5  11i
#  6 amp333i 6 333i
```

Grouping using pipes/`group_by` and get group means.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(y))

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   id     mean
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 11i     4  
# 2 22i     2.5
# 3 333i    4
```

There are `tidyverse` alternatives for the above, e.g. `str_sub()` and `str_length()` within `mutate()`.